# How to generate WSDD based on code or based on WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I have access to remote sever that provides me wsdl back to my response.

I prepared Client for this, based on that wsdl.

Now I woud like to write a fake Server (for testing needs), what I should start first? Which steps I should implement? The test makes sense only if it is implemented by this WSDL. Is it possible to generate some kind of Service with empty methods?

In my app I use Apache Axis 1.4

My steps, how I think:

1. I already have: **InterfacePortType** class (which, as I understand, represents the remote Server), which was generated for my client based on wsdl. So I can implement it, and it would be **MyService**:

   class **MyServer** implements **InterfacePortType**
2. Then generate somehow **WSDD**. How I can do it?

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805193/how-to-create-the-wsdd-file-for-this-webservice) not answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I generated WSDD using axistools-maven-plugin, setting:  serverSide parameter to **true** - then it generates the WSDD file.

This is maven plugin part:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wsdl2java-job</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>
                    src/main/config/wsdl2java/myfolder
                </sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${generatedSourcesDirectory}
                </outputDirectory>
                <testCases>false</testCases>
                <serverSide>true</serverSide>
                <subPackageByFileName>false</subPackageByFileName>
                <packageSpace>my.api</packageSpace>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **stubs** for the client side and **skeletons** for the server side.
Google this for more info: axis generate skeleton from wsdl

Comment: this is general info. I guess those skeletons are generated on the fly (once) when client is connecting to the AxisServlet which is in my web.xml configured to handle all this things. So, the questions is: how to generate WSDD by WSDL. Now my Service is able to ge the request from client and send the response back, but the client is not able to handle it, because this xml response is slightly different from that this client requires, because of WSDD (deployment descriptor) on the server.

Comment: it seems it is related to this topic: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201107.mbox/%3Cp06240803ca3a7269184d@%5B10.1.125.126%5D%3E

they use there axistools-maven-plugin to generate WSDD. Will try it.

Comment: You dont need to guess anything - just read around about stubs and skeletons! You need to generate stubs for your client and separately generate skeletons for your test service. Both can then work together, or you can use the client with the "real" service.

Comment: I see you have an answer so I will politely give up

Comment: thanks for help. I was not alone! there are stubs and skeletons in any case.