# Configuring WSDD to match the WSDL in AXIS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis, jax-rpc

I have WSDL (I got it from external provider). There are lines like this:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="SalesRequest">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="merchantid" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
                    ...
                </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>

  ... 
  <message name="SalesResponse">
        <part name="request" type="tns:SalesResponse"/>
  </message>
  ..
  <portType name="InterfacePortType">
    <operation name="Sales">
        <documentation>some text</documentation>
        <input message="tns:SalesRequest"/>
        <output message="tns:SalesResponse"/>
  </operation>
```

I've generated Java classes based on this WSDL (using JAX-RPC).

Then I created Axis Service (MyService implements InterfacePortType).

I prepared XSDD file do deploy MyService to web app.

So, then I call one of the my methods of MySerive and got this error in the moment of response serialization on the server side:

**unexpected element name: expected=request, actual=SalesReturn**

It means that my XSDL and XSDD do not much it other. MyService prepared response like this (but count not send it via the net):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope 
...
<SalesReturn href="#id0"/></ns1:SalesResponse><multiRef xmlns:ns2=
...
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The question is: What I should do with WSDD in order to have the **'request'** instead of **'SalesReturn'** in response XML from service?

I have not idea where this '**Return**' suffix came from.

-- some steps I already did:

I googled, and found that WSDL should have 'schema elementFormDefault="qualified"' in it. But I can not change WSDL, because it is external one, it was provided me by external provider.

Comment: it seems it is related to: http://ws-rx.blogspot.ca/2006/12/common-jaxrpc-error-unexpected-element.html

Comment: Did you use the same Wsdl to create the client and server parts? Ie did you start with the Wsdl each time?

Comment: nope. only for client. this the question, how to use one for both? I have asked this already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608282/how-to-generate-wsdd-based-on-code

Comment: Have a look at your other question - you need to generate both from the WSDL. This is usually allowed in most web services frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, I generated WSDD using **axistools-maven-plugin**, setting: serverSide parameter to **true** - then it generates the WSDD file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>wsdl2java-job</id>
                 <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <sourceDirectory>
                           src/main/config/wsdl2java/myfolder 
                       </sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${generatedSourcesDirectory} 
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <testCases>false</testCases>
                        <serverSide>true</serverSide>
                        <subPackageByFileName> false 
                        </subPackageByFileName>
                        <packageSpace> my.api 
                        </packageSpace>
                        </configuration>
                   </execution>
     </plugin>
```

Btw, when I launch this plugin it ends up with compilation exception, but, nevertheless, it could generated me WSDD.

Then if look at WSDD wich was generated, there are some interesting line that I did not have in my manually made WSDD:

```
<operation name="sales" qname="operNS:Sales" 
xmlns:operNS="urn:Interface" 
returnQName="request" 
returnType="rtns:SalesResponse" 
xmlns:rtns="urn:Interface" soapAction="urn:Interface#Sales" >
  <parameter qname="in" type="tns:SalesRequest" xmlns:tns="urn:Interface"/>
</operation>
```

This part: **returnQName="request"**

Also it generates "typeMapping" tags (but I used beanMapping)

So, as soon as I put this changes to my file I got everything working.

Actually, originally for generating my initial sources I have used another plugin: maven-antrun-plugin

But there were no option to generate WSDD.

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you is that request should looks like

`<soapenv:Envelope> 
   <request>
     <SalesRequest>...`

and you are sending

`<soapenv:Envelope> 
   <SalesReturn>...`

Best way to get this figure out is to try with a tool like SOAP UI and compare the payload they send with what you are generating from your tool - some tools have an option to wrap or unwrap the part name in the input/output messages.

hope this helps

Comment: I know it. I saw it. But how to fix it? This +Return is generated by sever automatically (i guess based on WSDD)